# How can I distinct count query by field in JPA specification?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have Specification class which implements JPA Specification interface:
`EntityClassSpecification implements Specification<EntityClass>`

I have overridden `toPredicate` method that looks like this:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<EntityClass> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    final Collection<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if (isNullOrEmpty(soilEntryCriteria.getField())) {
        query.groupBy(root.get("field"));
    }
    return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
}
```

The problem is, when I'm using this Specification for findAll(), which returns `Page<EntityClass>` result set, grouped by `field`, but when I get total count for pagination - it returns incorrect count, without grouping by `field`.

I tried to use `.distinct(true)`, `.countDistinct(root.get("field"))` and creating separate count query, which returns Long value, but every time jpql query for count doesn't change, and returns incorrect total value.

I think its time to ask for some help. Could you please suggest any tips how I can change this total count query for pagination?

Comment: Can you please share your generated sql(or jpql) for problematic cases? Total count and with group by field. If they don't have any where conditions they should be same, right?

Comment: define the JPQL (or SQL) that you are trying to achieve, and the associated entities. PS The JPA API has no such thing as a "Specification"; that is Spring Data ... a totally different API

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
On count query execution I see next jpql query: `select count(generatedAlias0) from EntityClass as generatedAlias0 where 1=1 group by generatedAlias0.field`.
I guess I'm trying to achieve select count(`generatedAlias0.field`) from EntityClass as generatedAlias0 where 1=1 group by generatedAlias0.field.

EntityClass consists from two fields - Integer id and  String field.

Comment: so why not post ALL of the JPA Criteria code? You say the problem is in the SELECT but dont post the JPA Criteria `select` call

Comment: Right now I have sql like this `select count(id) from entity where 1 = 1 group by field;` but I want to have query like `select count(distinct field) from entity where 1 = 1 group by field;`

Comment: Currently looking for a way to make it `select count(distinct field)` instead of `select distinct count(distinct field)` as well. By the way, your issue regarding incorrect total elements value, check this out https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-945

Comment: Did anyone solve this issue? I got the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this approach:

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) 
{

    // Count Query?
    if (query.getResultType().toString().contains("java.lang.Long")) {
        root.join("<MyJoinEntity>");
    } else {
        root.fetch("<MyJoinEntity>");
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

M.b. it's a little better (based on @Rafael Gava answer):

```
private static boolean isCountQuery(CriteriaQuery<?> query) {
    return query.getResultType().getAnnotation(Entity.class) == null;
}
```